# Getting a value from a JSON array inside an object

Tags: jquery, ajax, arrays, json, google-api

I am trying to fetch a value from a JSONP web-service, but I am not sure how to get the value from this JSON array.

```
$('#bookThumbnaill').attr('src', bookDetails.volumeInfo.imageLinks.thumbnail);
$('#bookTitle').text(bookDetails.volumeInfo.title);
//this one does not work!
$('#ISBN').text(bookDetails.volumeInfo.industryIdentifiers.type);
```

This is the document from the API it says how is the data returned

[Api Document](https://developers.google.com/books/docs/v1/reference/volumes)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`industryIdentifiers` is an array so you will need to access it's elements by index, not by name:

```
var industryIdentifiers = bookDetails.volumeInfo.industryIdentifiers; //get a reference to the array for brevity

for(var i=0; i< industryIdentifiers.length; i++) { //loop through all industryIdentifiers
    var type = industryIdentifiers[i].type; //access industryIdentifiers by index
    if(type === 'ISBN_10') { //test if this is the ISBN_10 identifier
        $('#ISBN').text(type);
    }
}
```

Comment: `for(var i=0; i< industryIdentifiers.length; i++) {
    var identifier = industryIdentifiers[i].type; //access identifiers by index
    //do something here with the identifier object
    $('#ISBN').text(identifier.ISBN_10);
}
});`

Comment: this is  not working, can't figure out how to extract the ISBN_10 type and assigning it to a selector

Comment: @LaliPali The snippet you posted in your comment won't work because your are trying to use a variable called `identifier`, which doesn't exist. You need to access the `industryIdentifiers` array by index, to get the `type` property: `$('#ISBN').text(industryIdentifiers[i].type);` Note that this is an array, so you can have more than one identifier

Comment: @LaliPali I update my answer to show how to add only the ISBN_10 identifier value to the `#ISBN` element.

Comment: how would you change it, so it can also take the right identifier, for example the ISBN_10 in this case is easy coz is the first one, but what if it was second in the iteration ?

Comment: @LaliPali The code above will loop through all industryIdentifiers, not just the first. You might want to read up on accessing javascript arrays: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Comment: I know I meant, what if you want to use only the second identifier for to ad to the #ISBN tag